# Run Photoshop in terminal

Tags: cmd, terminal, command, jsx, photoshop

My goal is to have Photoshop open a PSD file, change the text and an image, and then save the whole thing. All this should happen in the terminal. I have a Windows system.

I found out in the course of my research that it works with a jsx file. It is a simple script language.

My two questions:
How can I start Photoshop + load my PSD + run my jsx script with one command?

And is it possible to run the whole thing in a terminal without starting Photoshop visually? Since I only need the final result and not the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly run a script from Photoshop once it has started using the Scripts Event Manager. (on Application start). It's not well documented and you'll have to play around with it to get what you want. You can also drag a .jsx script onto Photoshop icon in order to run that script.

Starting Photoshop from a batch file? I'm sure it's possible, but I've not tried it.
You can also create a droplet which is an .exe that will run your script - but will ultimately open Photoshop.

Running the the script in a terminal without starting Photoshop visually? No, it doesn't have that kind of GIMP image processing style.